# View Linux module source file after preprocessed

Tags: linux, gcc, device-driver

When compiling with gcc we can view preprocessed source files with option -E. How can we apply this to the Makefile of kernel modules (external compile). The source files contain a lot of #ifdef #else #endif, is there a way to quick check which parts of code are actually included in the compiled file. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you try adding `CFLAGS=-E` to your `make` invocation?

Comment: You're right. When I added `CFLAGS=-E` to the `Makefile`, instead of producing object file, it produced preprocessed source file. Thank a lot Sarnold

Comment: Note that if your module is compiled from more than one source file, you may have to also change the output files from .o to .i in the Makefile. Otherwise you may get an unrecognized format error from the Make scripts. It would be nice if there were a better way around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `CFLAGS=-E` to your `make` invocation.